# Rails - Allow a model to associate with existing objects or create a new one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Let's say I have a two models, `Event` and `Person`. An event has a coordinator that is a person:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :coordinator, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => 'coordinator_id'
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :coordinator
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, :length => 20
end
```

In my form, I would like to let the user pick from existing People objects (let's say a list of radio buttons), but also have a text box to create a new Person (with the name entered in the text box).

How would I elegantly implement this? I can figure it out, but it involves a lot of ugly code in the Controller, and is a pain to validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done something similar in which the radio buttons set person[id] and then I just checked for the id.

So in my controller#create method:

```
if params[:person][:id]
   @person = Person.find(params[:person][:id])
else
   @person = Person.new(params[:person])
   #Handle saving @person here.
end
```

You may have to delete the `id` param in the `else`block if the form sends it even if nothing is selected.

**Edit to answer validation question:**

In the `#Handle saving @person here.` is where you'd do what you normally do for creating an object.  Like:

```
if @person.save
  flash[:notice] = "User created successfully"
else
  render :action => 'new' # (or whatever the action is)
  return
end
```

Comment: I did forget to mention that there is some validation code on Person. Would this handle that well?

Comment: After some tweaking to fields_for I think I got it figured out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The validation code on person, will be executed everytime you save a person.
To save bypassing the validator, write @person.save(**false**).
Hope it integrate the pcg79's answer